# mailog parsing using perl

Tags: perl, dovecot

I have a mailog file in /var/log/mailog. The content structure is as shown below:

```
Feb 13 10:13:24 mailer dove: imap-login: Login: user=<test@test.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::ffff:14.012.251.125, lip=::ffff:33.01.121.12.80
Feb 13 10:13:25 mailer dove: imap-login: Disconnected: rip=::ffff:10.100.2.10, lip=::ffff:33.01.121.12.81
Feb 13 10:13:25 mailer dove: pop3-login: Disconnected: rip=::ffff:10.100.2.10, lip=::ffff:33.01.121.12.81
Feb 13 10:13:25 mailer dove: pop3-login: Disconnected: rip=::ffff:10.100.2.10, lip=::ffff:33.01.121.12.80
Feb 13 10:13:25 mailer dove: imap-login: Disconnected: rip=::ffff:10.100.2.10, lip=::ffff:33.01.121.12.80
Feb 13 10:13:26 mailer dove: POP3(info@nbb.com): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/24, size=187461
Feb 13 10:13:26 mailer dove: pop3-login: Login: user=<info@bb.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::ffff:14.012.251.125, lip=::ffff:33.01.121.12.80
Feb 13 10:13:26 mailer dove: POP3(sup@bb.com): Disconnected for inactivity top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/32, size=473758028
Feb 13 10:13:26 mailer dove: POP3(docs@bb.com): Disconnected for inactivity top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/9, size=140778365
Feb 13 10:13:26 mailer dove: pop3-login: Login: user=<jos@bb.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=::ffff:14.012.251.125, lip=::ffff:33.01.121.12.80
Feb 13 10:13:28 mailer dove: POP3(jos@bb.net): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=1/8336, del=1/1, size=8319
Feb 13 10:13:28 mailer dove: pop3-login: Login: user=<hello@abb.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::ffff:21.254.145.12, lip=::ffff:33.01.121.12.
```

I want to be able to parse this using perl to extract and group the number of occurrence a user has appeared in the log and sort it with the highest size on the top.

I have tried below, but this only prints every user;

```
perl -ne 
 '$l{$2}=$1 if /^(.{15}) .* imap-login: 
  Login: user=<([^>]+)>/; END 
  { 
    print "$_ last imap-login: $l{$_}\n" 
    for keys %l 
  }' /var/log/maillog
```

Can you help me tweak this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
perl -lne '
    $h{$1}++ if /imap-login:\s+Login:\s+user=<([^>]+)>/;
    END{
        foreach my $key (sort { $h{$a} <=> $h{$b} } keys(%h)) {
            print $key, " ", $h{$key}
        }
    }
' /var/log/mail.log
```

**EDIT**

If you'd like to add access time, work around this :

```
perl -wlne '
    do{
        $h{$2}{inc}++;
        $h{$2}{time}="$2";
    } if /^(\w+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+).*?Login:\s+user=<([^>]+)>/;
    END{
        use Data::Dumper;
        print Dumper \%h;
    }
'
```

You just have to parse the HASH.

Comment: Nice sputnick! Quick one, Can you help sort this by size in ascending order and perhaps remove dupes ;-)

Comment: Brilliant! Quick bother thought, can I add latest access time to this to?!

Comment: Can you show a bit of search effort ? You just need to modify the regex to add a second capture...

Comment: Forgive on this one sputnick not pretty sharp on perl and regex. I have tried `perl -lne '$h{$1}++ if /^(.{15}).*imap-login:\s+Login:\s+user=<([^>]+)>/;END` with no joy.